# Unauthorized Access for Access Token

Tags: c#, square-connect

I am testing out the Square API and I am able to retrieve all my customers back from the /v2/customers endpoint using PostMan.  It works with both my production and sandbox accesstoken that I got from the dashboard.

When I test using C#, I always get the following error.

`"{\"errors\":[{\"category\":\"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR\",\"code\":\"UNAUTHORIZED\",\"detail\":\"This request could not be authorized.\"}]}"`

I am using the same access token for sure, I've double checked a billion times.  It doesn't work with my sandbox token either.

This is the line of C# code I am using to call the ListCustomers endpoint.

`var customers = _customerApi.ListCustomers("Bearer " + accessToken);`

I also tried using the ApiClient to hit the endpoint explicitly but that gave the same result.

I cannot figure out at this point what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out...

Using Fiddler I was able to see that when you insert

`"Bearer " + accessToken`

It ends up actually as

`"Authorization: Bearer Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

Even though the documentation states that it needs to include the "Bearer" piece, this is in fact incorrect.

Now I am getting back responses.

Comment: Square is working on removing the authorization parameter from each request to make the SDKs easier to use. You can see the work in progress in the [2.1.0 branch of the Square C# SDK](https://github.com/square/connect-csharp-sdk/tree/release/2.1.0)